# Which 3GPP spec identifies the maximim number of PDP Contexts a UE can activate?

Tags: umts

So I know that the network limit on the max number of contexts a UE can activate is 11. However, I can't find in the 3GPP specs where this is stated explicitly. I've been searching for hours now and can't find anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've figured it out. It turns out I needed a little bit more time to continue digging. The limit is specified indirectly through the number of available NSAPIs that can be assigned. The number of NSAPIs is limited by the definition of the NSAPI IE specified in TS 24.008 (I'm using Rel4 for this, the situation may have changes in later releases) section 10.5.6.2. The definition allocates 4 bits to the NSAPI which encodes 11 NSAPIs and 5 reserved values. Since each PDP context needs to be allocated a specific NSAPI then there can only be a max of 11 PDP contexts because there is only 11 NSAPIs available.